# How to apply two pixel shaders in one go

Tags: directx9, slimdx

Is there any possible way to apply two pixel shader simultaneously in directx-9.
For example I am having two pixel shaders one to apply ripple effect and another to modify the color of the texture rendered on the screen. Is there any way that I can render the effect of the two pixel shaders simultaneously without combining them in the same shader file.
Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to render the results of the first to a texture, then read the texture in the second shader and output the results to the screen.